# How to control secondary circuit using TTL

Tags: ttl

I have a very newbie and possibly stupid question, but I have been searching many sites and just can't find an answer.

Imagine you have a circuit, some device (electro-motor) that is powered with for example 20V dc power supply. Then you have another TTL circuit.

I am able to programatically change the output on TTL circuit to 0 (0,8V) or 1 (5V), but what I need to do is control the second circuit, using this digital output, that means, for example if I send 1 to output, the 20V device is switched on, when I send 0, it's turned off.

What is a simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very classic case to use a transistor as a switch.

Example:
[image]
[Simulate circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+1+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0At+400+256+464+256+0+1+-19.90146045327826+0.09853954519174221+100.0%0Ar+464+144+464+240+0+300.0%0Aw+464+272+464+304+0%0Ag+464+304+464+352+0%0AR+464+144+464+96+0+0+40.0+20.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+320+256+400+256+0+1000.0%0AR+256+256+208+256+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0As+256+256+320+256+0+1+false%0Ao+1+64+0+35+20.0+0.1+0+-1%0Ao+0+64+6+35+20.0+9.765625E-5+1+-1%0A)

- The 300 Ohm resistor would be your load
- The 1k resistor limits the base current
- The 50Hz source simulates your 5V TTL output

Note that there are some things to consider when dimensioning the circuit. The transistor must be chosen to  satisfy the collector current requirements. There are some other considerations, but this answer is not about transistor circuits in detail. There a plenty of resources in the WWW. Search for "transistor as a switch" and "emitter follower".

Comment: I am still confused about 1 thing, I am testing this circuit on qucs and it tells me there is 20V on load even if there is a very low voltage (0.1V which represent logical 0 in TTL) on base. Is this some kind of bug in qucs or there is something more in this...

Comment: @Petr: Given my example, the 20V will always be there. There is just no current flow "possible" as long as the transistor is "switched off" (base voltage at least about 1V). Or what do you mean?

Comment: now I see I am getting 20V on 0V on base and nearly 0V with 5V on base, that explains this, so in this circuit logical 0 turns the secondary circuit on, that confused me

Comment: What do you use to simulate the "load"? If there is no resistance, the emitter could indeed read 0V (and the transistor would blow up in real life).

Comment: I created exactly the same schema as you sent here, there is 300 ohm resistor, when I put 0 - 0.8V on ttl output I see 19.5V on load, with 2 - 5V on ttl I see 0.1 V on load. This is basically what I needed.

Comment: If you "measure" this at the junction between the load and the transistor against GND its fine.

Comment: I installed java to my pc and ran that applet you linked, the similar issues as in application I use occur there as well: when I put 0.8V on digital output (logical zero) the circuit is activated as well (but it display 4V instead of 19.9V on secondary circuit) perhaps I should use some more components to ensure that the secondary circuit isn't activated even when logical zero has its maximal value (0.8V) instead of 0V

Comment: At 0,8V the transistor already starts "switching", that is to be expected. Are you sure that your maximum output low voltage is 0,8V? What TTL part are you using to drive the base? You could reduce the amount of base drive by increasing the resistor which will then reduce the collector current. As I said, this is about dimensioning the circuit according to specific requirements. Read up on the theory if this is unclear!

Comment: No TBH I don't know what maximum output low voltage would be in my case, but according to specifications, in TTL logical 0 is 0 to 0.8V and logical 1 is 2V to 5V, so in theory there could be 0.8V on 0 and only 2V on 1

Comment: While 0-0.8V is probably defined as valid INPUT low voltage \$ V_il <= 0.8 \$, this does not mean that your TTL output would output up to 0.8V. There normally is a safety margin. You have to look at the OUTPUT low voltage which is about \$ V_ol <= 0.4V \$ for TTL.

Comment: ok in theory this works, in practice it's not. I have created a circuit that uses shift registers, d flip-flops and should control some devices that are running on secondary circuit using this. It works fine as long as these devices are simple leds which need low power to work. 1 led (2.2V + rezistor 200ohm) works fine on this 5V circuit, but small electro motor doesn't even start up. Is this related to rezistor parameters? do I need a different rezistor for high-power devices? I figured that if I remove the rezistor between digital output and base it works but tranzistor is very hot

Comment: I meant * do I need a different transistor, not resistor :-) unfortunately comment can't be edited anymore :/

Answer (score -1):

A "high side" switch handles high current from low logic control to higher voltage output.

These are very low cost, smart , and tiny SMD which may be soldered with a tiny oven. There are many similar alternatives.

If this is too hard, look at how it is made in the schematic. http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FP/FPF1203.pdf

Comment: I have no idea if this answer is useful to me, but I would like to know why it got downvoted -2? Is it totally irrelevant or something?

Comment: @Petr: The answer is somewhat confusing and bad choice of words. The second sentence is irrelevant to your question. Maybe the language barrier.